# Parent process still receive signal while being suspended

Tags: c, linux, signals, system

I'm studying about processes in Linux programming, there is this code that I cannot understand. As far as I know when a process is suspended, it does not receive signals (except the one that wakes it), but in this code, when the parent process is running, it calls `wait`, but it still print out counter, which means it received SIGUSR1. Can anyone explain this?

I already know the order or running is arbitrary, if the child process runs first then there is no problem, but what if the parent runs first?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
pid_t pid;
int counter = 0;
int status;
void handler1(int sig){counter ++;
  printf("counter = %d\n", counter);
  fflush(stdout);
  kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
}void handler2(int sig){counter += 3;
  printf("counter = %d\n", counter);
  exit(0);
}
int main() {
  signal(SIGUSR1, handler1);
  if ((pid = fork()) != 0) {
    pid_t p;
    if ((p = wait(&status)) > 0) {
      counter += 2;
      printf("counter = %d\n", counter);
    }
  } else {
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler2);
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    while(1) {};
  }
}
```

I expect the program will be suspended, but it runs well every time.

Comment: waiting does not mean being suspended

Comment: Can you explain more, here is the linux manual about `wait`: `The wait() system call suspends execution of the calling thread until one of its children terminates`

Comment: "*suspending execution*" in this context is different from "suspending a process" as when having sent it a `SIGSTOP` signal. You are facing a language issue here.

Comment: ^^ this.  For `wait()`, "suspends execution" just describes ordinary blocking.  The process is still schedulable, and can therefore receive signals.  The fact that its documentation specifies that it can fail with `EINTR` makes this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Processes always receive signals if they don't ignore them (`signal(SIGnum, SIG_IGN);`).

Unignored signals can be deferred by setting a signal mask (e.g., with `sigprocmask`, unmasking them then causes the pending signals to be delivered) or they're deferred if the process is stopped (with `SIGSTOP`/`SIGTSTOP`; sending `SIGCONT` to the processes causes the pending signals to be delivered). (Note that non-realtime signals may be coalesced. You may, for example, receive a signal only once when it was sent 3 times.)

Blocking calls like `wait` block/suspend the process until they're finished or until a signal delivery interrupts them.

Masking a signal (e.g., with `sigprocmask`) is sometimes called blocking the signal (from being deliverable), but that's different from a blocking syscall that blocks/sleeps/suspends the process (blocks it from running on a CPU).

Comment: Quibble: implementations don't necessarily queue multiple signals of the same type to the same process, which can be construed as ignoring a (new) signal if another of the same type is already pending.  Also, this answer would be improved by observing that `wait()` in particular is explicitly documented to be (allowed to be) interruptible by signal.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: [just for completeness] "*implementations don't necessarily queue multiple signals of the same type to the same process*" they do for `SIGCHLD`s.